# Augmenting a matrix with a highly-incorrelated column

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, correlation

Consider a binary matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\  -1 & 1 &1 \\ \vdots & \vdots &\vdots \\ 1 & 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

with a random distribution of 1 and -1 scattered throughout the matrix. Say that we need to add **another** column vector made also made of -1's and +1's  to this matrix with:

1. Roughly the **same number** of 1's and -1's
2. As **incorrelated** as possible with any other column (i.e. Pearson correlation of the new column with any other column as **close to 0** as possible)

There could certainly be multiple solutions to this problem. Does this problem have a name? Any known family of algorithms or heuristics to solve it?